# Distinguishing Production logs and staging logs

Tags: python, django, django-logging

I have logging enabled in my django app, I receive all `ERRORS` related logs on my configured emails.
*But I am unable to distinguish whether an error has occurred on **PRODUCTION** or **STAGING** system.*

Should I change some logging setting, or is there any way to add some environment variable in subject of the email?

Here is my logging code in settings:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add formatters and put your environment there:

```
'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': 'PRODUCTION %(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': 'PRODUCTION %(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
```